# Tengo problemas para mostrar la cantidad restante de días, entre la fecha de realización de una actividad a hoy

Tags: php, mysql

Chicos, me presento con la siguiente duda,

Tengo un sistema de inscripción a cursos en PHP, y en parte del sitio muestro los datos del curso, su fecha de realización y cuantos días faltan para que se realice, sin embargo, agregue una fecha de realización de 2 meses en adelante y no me muestra la cantidad de días correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código PHP que uso para esta parte es el siguiente:

```html
/*Codigo para ver cuantos días quedan disponibles del curso */ 
   $OldDate = strtotime("$registro->fechas_curso");
   $NewDate = date('d-m-Y', $OldDate);
   $diff = date_diff(date_create($NewDate),date_create(date("d-m-Y")));
   $diff2 = $diff->format('%d día(s)');
```

¿Cual creen que pueda ser el problema?

De antemano, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Puedes consultar la siguiente pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2019-05-31");//fecha actual
$date2 = new DateTime("2019-06-15");//fecha de inicio del curso
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $diff->days . ' days ';
```

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma, agrega la fecha de hoy y la fecha de realización de tu curso y el resultado en este ejemplo será:

```
15 days
```

Comment: Lo agregue y le hice unos cambios con mi código: 


$date1 = new DateTime('d-m-Y');//fecha actual
$date2 = new DateTime("$registro->fechas_curso");//fecha de inicio del curso
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $diff->days . ' days ';




Sin embargo, se queda cargando sin respuesta

Comment: Verifica que cumpla con el formato de fecha de tu consulta.

Comment: Copie y pegue tu codigo, exactamente como en el ejemplo que diste y me dio el siguiente eco: 6015 days